# Issue with compressed SAMLResponse from WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS for SAML 2.0 SSO implementation, where the service provider is implemented in C# using component space library. After user gets authenticated against SSO login page, it gets redirected to Service Provider with SAML Response which is compressed and then base64 encoded. The C# client, which is using component space library, is expecting an XML string after base64 decode of SAML resonse, which is not the case with WSO2 response. Is this standard to send SAML responses in compressed form? Is there a standard algorithms used for this compression?

Is it a bug in WSo2?

Answer (score 0):

The IS 4.1.0 is using the 4.0.7 tag for the sso/saml provider implementation. Assuning that you are using 4.1.0 you can find teh compression/encoding/marhsalling here:
http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/4.0.7/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/saml/util/SAMLSSOUtil.java 
Other distributions use similar or the same implementation, in this case you have to look through the wso2-jungle. I guess you have to find an opensaml library for c# which is helping you with the unmarshall-process. As I understood your coments you already figured out how to uncompress and decode the response, so only unmarshall is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's a known bug in IS 4.1.0, and this is fixed in the latest version: IS 4.5.0

According to the SAML specifications, response using the POST binding should not be compressed, only base64 encoded.